# Iteratively apply a function that updates one of its arguments at each step (PySpark)

Tags: python, apache-spark, for-loop, pyspark

I am working on a pyspark implementation of the Louvain algorithm for community detection. In a nutshell, the algorithm greedily takes one node and assigns it to the community that causes the greatest increase in a purity metric. This process is sequentially iterated to each node in the graph.

By construction, the communities change at each step. For example, assigning node *i* from community *X* to community *Y* implies that at the start of the next step, community *Y* will have grown by one member. This affects the optimal community of node *i+1*.

I wrote a function that reassigns a node to its optimal neighboring community. Currently, I am using a `for` loop to apply the function to each node in the graph and update the graph's edges at each step (and yes, it's as slow as you'd expect).

The function receives a node ID and a pyspark dataframe as arguments and returns a community ID. This ID is then used to update the pyspark dataframe for the next iteration.

This is what the dataframe that is being updated looks like:

```py
>>> edges.show()
+---+---+----+----+
|src|dst|cSrc|cDst|
+---+---+----+----+
|  0|  1|  40|  41|
|  0|  2|  40|  42|
|  1|  2|  41|  42|
+---+---+----+----+
```

It represents the edges of an undirected graph. `src` is the ID of the source node and `dst` is the ID of the destination node. Columns `cSrc` and `cDst` represent the community that `src` and `dst` currently belong to (respectively).

This is what my code looks like:

```py
# Define function that finds the best community ID
def getOptimalCommunity(nodeId, edges) -> int:
    # Do a ton of smart stuff here to determine `optimalCommunityId`
    return optimalCommunityId

# Apply to each node ID in the graph
for i in [0, 1, 2]:
    # Get optimal community
    comm = getOptimalCommunity(nodeId=i, edges=edges)

    # Update `edges`
    edges = (edges
        .selectExpr(
            'src',
            'dst',
            # Update the community that `i` belongs to
            f'case when src = i then {comm} else cSrc end as cSrc',
            f'case when dst = i then {comm} else cDst end as cDst'
        )
    )
```

---

## Question

In PySpark, is there a more efficient way to apply a function that updates one of its arguments?